# App crashes due to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column ' burnerSize' does not exist

Tags: android, database, cursor, android-sqlite, not-exists

In my android application, here is how i create a table :

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Creating database [" + DATABASE_NAME + " v." + DATABASE_VERSION + "]...");
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(UserORM.SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(EnquiryORM.SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SiteVisitORM.SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SiteVisitModelORM.SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(ReferenceImageORM.SQL_CREATE_TABLE);

}

/**
 * Called when the DATABASE_VERSION is increased.
 *
 * @param sqLiteDatabase
 * @param oldVersion
 * @param newVersion
 */

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Upgrading database ["+DATABASE_NAME+" v." + oldVersion+"] to ["+DATABASE_NAME+" v." + newVersion+"]...");

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(UserORM.SQL_DROP_TABLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(EnquiryORM.SQL_DROP_TABLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SiteVisitORM.SQL_DROP_TABLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SiteVisitModelORM.SQL_DROP_TABLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(ReferenceImageORM.SQL_DROP_TABLE);

    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

}
```

SitevisitModelORM contain the code

```
 public static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +

                COLUMN_ID + " " + COLUMN_ID_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_SITE_VISIT_ID + " " + COLUMN_SITE_VISIT_ID_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +

                COLUMN_KITCHEN_NAME + " " + COLUMN_KITCHEN_NAME_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_KITCHEN_MODE + " " + COLUMN_KITCHEN_MODE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_COOKING_STYLE + " " + COLUMN_COOKING_STYLE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_COOKING_TYPE + " " + COLUMN_COOKING_TYPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_KITCHEN_USAGE + " " + COLUMN_KITCHEN_USAGE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_KITCHEN_TYPE + " " + COLUMN_KITCHEN_TYPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_STORAGE_TYPE + " " + COLUMN_STORAGE_TYPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_STORAGE_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_STORAGE_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_SINK + " " + COLUMN_SINK_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_SINK_REMARKS + " " + COLUMN_SINK_REMARKS_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_GAS_SERVICE_TYPE + " " + COLUMN_GAS_SERVICE_TYPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_CYLINDER_NUMBER + " " + COLUMN_CYLINDER_NUMBER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_COLOR + " " + COLUMN_COLOR_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_TEXTURE_PREFERENCE + " " + COLUMN_TEXTURE_PREFERENCE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_LED + " " + COLUMN_LED_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_LED_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_LED_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_LED_REMARKS + " " + COLUMN_LED_REMARKS_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +

                COLUMN_REFRIDGERATOR + " " + COLUMN_REFRIDGERATOR_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_REFRIDGERATOR_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_REFRIDGERATOR_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_REFRIDGERATOR_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_REFRIDGERATOR_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_WINE_COOLER + " " + COLUMN_WINE_COOLER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_WINE_COOLER_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_WINE_COOLER_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_WINE_COOLER_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_WINE_COOLER_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_AQUA_GUARD + " " + COLUMN_AQUA_GUARD_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_AQUA_GUARD_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_AQUA_GUARD_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_AQUA_GUARD_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_AQUA_GUARD_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +

                COLUMN_WATER_POT + " " + COLUMN_WATER_POT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_WATER_POT_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_WATER_POT_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_WATER_POT_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_WATER_POT_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_GEYSER + " " + COLUMN_GEYSER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_GEYSER_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_GEYSER_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_GEYSER_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_GEYSER_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_MIXER + " " + COLUMN_MIXER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_MIXER_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_MIXER_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_MIXER_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_MIXER_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_JUICER + " " + COLUMN_JUICER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_JUICER_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_JUICER_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_JUICER_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_JUICER_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_TOASTER + " " + COLUMN_TOASTER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_TOASTER_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_TOASTER_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_TOASTER_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_TOASTER_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_FLOUR_MILL + " " + COLUMN_FLOUR_MILL_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_FLOUR_MILL_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_FLOUR_MILL_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_FLOUR_MILL_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_FLOUR_MILL_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_WET_GRINDER + " " + COLUMN_WET_GRINDER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_WET_GRINDER_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_WET_GRINDER_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_WET_GRINDER_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_WET_GRINDER_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_MANDIR + " " + COLUMN_MANDIR_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_MANDIR_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_MANDIR_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_MANDIR_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_MANDIR_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_LOFT_REQUIREMENT + " " + COLUMN_LOFT_REQUIREMENT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_LOFT_REQUIREMENT_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_LOFT_REQUIREMENT_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_LOFT_REQUIREMENT_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_LOFT_REQUIREMENT_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +


                COLUMN_CHIMNEY + " " + COLUMN_CHIMNEY_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_CHIMNEY_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_CHIMNEY_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_CHIMNEY_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_CHIMNEY_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_BURNER + " " + COLUMN_BURNER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_BURNER_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_BURNER_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_BURNER_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_BURNER_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_DISH_WASHER + " " + COLUMN_DISH_WASHER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_DISH_WASHER_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_DISH_WASHER_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_DISH_WASHER_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_DISH_WASHER_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_WASHING_MACHINE + " " + COLUMN_WASHING_MACHINE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_WASHING_MACHINE_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_WASHING_MACHINE_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_WASHING_MACHINE_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_WASHING_MACHINE_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_MICROWAVE + " " + COLUMN_MICROWAVE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_MICROWAVE_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_MICROWAVE_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_MICROWAVE_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_MICROWAVE_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_OVEN + " " + COLUMN_OVEN_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_OVEN_SCOPE + " " + COLUMN_OVEN_SCOPE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_OVEN_SIZE + " " + COLUMN_OVEN_SIZE_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +

                COLUMN_DATE_OF_POSSESSION + " " + COLUMN_DATE_OF_POSSESSION_TYPE +

                ")";


public static final String SQL_DROP_TABLE =
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
```

and methods :

```
 public static SiteVisitModel findSiteVisitModelById(Context context, int svModelId) {

    DatabaseWrapper databaseWrapper = new DatabaseWrapper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase database = databaseWrapper.getReadableDatabase();

    SiteVisitModel svm = null;
    if (database != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Loading SiteVisitModel[" + svModelId + "]...");
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SiteVisitModelORM.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + SiteVisitModelORM.COLUMN_ID + " = " + svModelId, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            svm = cursorToSiteVisitModel(cursor);
            //enquiry.setTags(TagORM.getTagsForPost(context, post));
            Log.d(TAG, "Sitevisitmodel loaded successfully! with sitevisitmodel id" + svm.getId());
        }

        cursor.close();
        database.close();
    }
    return svm;
}
```

when i call the below method to insert into the table, i get some error.

```
public static long insertSiteVisitModel(Context context, SiteVisitModel svModel) {

    Log.d("n", "inside insertSiteVisitModel().........");

    if ((findSiteVisitModelById(context, svModel.getId()) )!= null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SiteVisitModel already exists in database, not inserting!");
        return updateSiteVisitModel(context, svModel);
    }
    ContentValues values = siteVisitModelToContentValues(svModel);

    DatabaseWrapper databaseWrapper = new DatabaseWrapper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase database = databaseWrapper.getWritableDatabase();

    boolean success = false;
    long svmodelId=-1;
    try {
        if (database != null) {
            svmodelId = database.insert(SiteVisitModelORM.TABLE_NAME, "null", values);
            Log.d(TAG, "Inserted new SiteVisitModel with ID: " + svmodelId);

           /* for (Tag tag : post.getTags()) {
                TagORM.insertTag(context, tag, post.getId());
            }*/
            success = true;
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to insert SiteVisitModel[" + svModel.getId() + "] due to: " + ex);
    } finally {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
    }

    return svmodelId;
}
```

the error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column ' burnerSize' does not exist
                                                                     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:333)
                                                                     at com.example.anjana.hhys.orm.SiteVisitModelORM.cursorToSiteVisitModel(SiteVisitModelORM.java:709)
                                                                     at com.example.anjana.hhys.orm.SiteVisitModelORM.findSiteVisitModelById(SiteVisitModelORM.java:403)
                                                                     at com.example.anjana.hhys.orm.SiteVisitModelORM.insertSiteVisitModel(SiteVisitModelORM.java:426)
                                                                     at com.example.anjana.hhys.orm.SiteVisitORM.insertObjectsWithoutRepeatation(SiteVisitORM.java:889)
                                                                     at com.example.anjana.hhys.activity.MainActivity$6.onResponse(MainActivity.java:247)
                                                                     at com.example.anjana.hhys.activity.MainActivity$6.onResponse(MainActivity.java:217)
                                                                     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
                                                                     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
                                                                     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

i used getColumnIndex() instead of getColumnIndexOrThrow(),then i got the error that cursor cannot access the row 0 and column -1 of the table.

I am confused why this happens!i tried many solutions regarding the same problem.
But none of them worked.
Please help me!

Comment: if you have modified a column after installing application one time then first clear data and again open your application

Comment: Or handle upgrades in the database using SQLiteHelper or your own custom system

Comment: i will definitely try it! when i uninstalled the app, for the first time,all data inserted to table without any problem.then each time i try to update those data ,app crashes due to this error.I once again uninstalled and re installed app and again when inserting data only for the first time no problems occured!

Comment: clearing data of the app and opening again didn't helped!

Comment: Whitespace matters - you likely should not have a leading whitespace with your column name constant

Comment: it's worked! The problem was that silly white space! Thanks  @ laalto